# Requesting an image file (local and NOT an URL) for machine learning processing in python azure function app

Tags: azure-function-app

In the middle of developing an azure function app that receives an input image file through 'post' request. The image should be provided directly as an input (without storing it in an azure storage container) to a machine learning algorithm for processing. What is the snippet to get an image file and reading its content in python azure function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
try:
    image =  req.files.get('image') 
    uploadedImage = image.read()   # uploadedImage contains image data 
    .......
except Exception as e:
    logging.info(e)
```